# How can I expand all children of a specific modelindex in a QTreeView?

Tags: qt

I try this way:

```
void MainWindow::expandNode(const QModelIndex &parentIndex, bool expand) {
  tree->setExpanded(parentIndex, expand);
  for (qint32 rowNum = 0; rowNum < treeModel->rowCount(parentIndex); ++rowNum) {
    QModelIndex childIndex = treeModel->index(rowNum, 0, parentIndex);
    tree->setExpanded(childIndex, expand);
    expandNode(childIndex);
  }
}
```

But after some navigations through the tree it stops working. Furthermore selection model currentIndex keeps another node then I see on the screen.
I've already found some dicision here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5001013/3316930, but I do need to clarify the matter - what's happening with indexes and selection model?
Thanks in advance!

Solved: it was because of feedback between `QTabWidget` and `QTreeView` made by me.